# Совместимость geforce 9800 с W10

Tags: windows-10, драйвер

Для geforce 9800 gt нашел драйвера только для W7 и W8 - [Geforce 342.01 Driver](http://www.nvidia.ru/download/driverResults.aspx/112633/ru).
С ними на W10 выбивает иногда экран смерти "Video TDR Failure".
Можно ли обойти эту проблему?

Comment: По поводу именно этой проблемы не скажу, но сам стал использовать DriverPack - https://drp.su/ru , эта утилита сама находит новые и подходящие драйверы для всех компонентов компьютера и ставит их, вместо часов потраченых на поиск хороших драйверов теперь занимаюсь другими делами